# Undefined value when consuming rest API in C# .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

When performing crud operations in the api, it does it correctly. I test it with swagger and it returns the values ​​correctly from the API.

When I consume the API to display the data, I get the amount of data that is in the table but "undefined".

API:

```
public IEnumerable<Empleados> Get()
{
    return db.Empleados.ToList();
}
```

Calling the API:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Empleados>> GetAllEmpleados()
{
        _empleados = new List<Empleados>();

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(_clientHandler))
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44310/api/Empleados"))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _empleados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Empleados>>(apiResponse);
            }

            return _empleados;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<button onclick="GetAllEmpleados()" class="btn btn-primary">Mostrar Empleados</button>
    function GetAllEmpleados() {
        $.getJSON("/Empleados/GetAllEmpleados", function (empleados) {
            $("#tblEmpleados tbody tr").remove();
            $.map(empleados, function (empleado) {
                $("#tblEmpleados tbody").append("<tr>"
                    + "<td>" + empleado.IdEmpleado + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + empleado.Nombre + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + empleado.Posicion + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + empleado.Departamento + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + empleado.Supervisor + "</td>"
                    + "<td>"
                    + "           <button class='btn-success' onclick='Edit(" + empleado.IdEmpleado + ")' style='margin-right:5px;'>Edit</button>"
                    + "           <button class='btn-danger' onclick='Delete(" + empleado.IdEmpleado + ")'>Delete</button>"
                    + "</td>"
                    +"</tr>"
                );
            });
        });
    }
```

[The result is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAxux.png)

Comment: All caps is considered shouting on the Internet.

Comment: Also, your issue will be 100% on the javascript side. Something is different about your json vs what you expect. Unfortunately you left that key piece of information out of your question.

Comment: This is likely to be returning an error? Can you post that or debug to find it. Also HttpClient should never be in a using block as it is a shared object and disposing it is handled by the host due to the way web-sockets are implemented in C#

Comment: @blockingHD, no dont return error. 
it even brings me the correct amount of data, but all undefined in te view

Comment: Can you post the Empleados class?

Comment: ...and this question is still missing the necessary information for us to help.

Comment: Hi @JoelPeralta, any updates about this case? Have you resolved the problem?

Comment: yes, the problem was the controller where it called the Api.  @FeiHan

Comment: I would put the code, but it turns out wrong when I paste it here and I don't want any more scolding hahaha

Answer (score 0):

> When I consume the API to display the data, I get the amount of data that is in the table but "undefined".

Please try to check the actual data that your API returned, if the JSON property names are stylized as camelCase, like below.

And it will cause the issue while you access the data with `empleado.IdEmpleado` etc.

```
[{"idEmpleado":1,"nombre":"blabla"...
```

You can try to modify the code as below, then check if it can work well.

```
$.map(empleados, function (empleado) {
    $("#tblEmpleados tbody").append("<tr>"
        + "<td>" + empleado.idEmpleado + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + empleado.nombre + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + empleado.posicion + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + empleado.departamento + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + empleado.supervisor + "</td>"
        + "<td>"
        + "           <button class='btn-success' onclick='Edit(" + empleado.idEmpleado + ")' style='margin-right:5px;'>Edit</button>"
        + "           <button class='btn-danger' onclick='Delete(" + empleado.idEmpleado + ")'>Delete</button>"
        + "</td>"
        + "</tr>"
    );
});
```